# Order by max value of a column when its type list?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following df.

```
d<- data.frame (type=c("rna","rna","rna"), value = c(1,2,3) )
d2 <- data.frame (type=c("dna","dna"), value = c(20,30) )
d3 <- data.frame (type=c("protein","protein","protein"), value = c(-9.6,300, 1000) )
df <- rbind (d,d2,d3)

df$test = list ( c(0,12), 2, 3, 4,5,6,7, c(20,1) )

     type  value  test
1     rna    1.0 0, 12
2     rna    2.0     2
3     rna    3.0     3
4     dna   20.0     4
5     dna   30.0     5
6 protein   -9.6     6
7 protein  300.0     7
8 protein 1000.0 20, 1
```

What I like to do is order the column test from highest to lowest. However because test is a list, what I like to do is only use the max value.  For example, row 1 will be sorted using the value 12 and row 8 by 20.  So that if I order test by descending row 8 will be the first row follow by row row 2 and so on.  I can order when the column is a numeric type but stump when its a list especially when there are multiple values in each element.  thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sapply(..., max)` to extract the maximum from each vector and then sort by it:

```
df %>% arrange(desc(sapply(test, max)))

#     type  value  test
#1 protein 1000.0 20, 1
#2     rna    1.0 0, 12
#3 protein  300.0     7
#4 protein   -9.6     6
#5     dna   30.0     5
#6     dna   20.0     4
#7     rna    3.0     3
#8     rna    2.0     2
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyverse` tools: we can use `purrr::map_dbl` to get the `max` value of the 'test' column and use that in `arrange(desc())`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  arrange(desc(map_dbl(test, max)))
#      type  value  test
#1 protein 1000.0 20, 1
#2     rna    1.0 0, 12
#3 protein  300.0     7
#4 protein   -9.6     6
#5     dna   30.0     5
#6     dna   20.0     4
#7     rna    3.0     3
#8     rna    2.0     2
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
 .Label = c("rna", "dna", "protein"), class = "factor"), 
 value = c(1, 2, 3, 20, 30, -9.6, 300, 1000), 
 test = list(c(0, 12), 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, c(20, 1))),
  row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R we can do

```
df[order(sapply(df$test, max), decreasing=TRUE), ]

# type  value  test
# 8 protein 1000.0 20, 1
# 1     rna    1.0 0, 12
# 7 protein  300.0     7
# 6 protein   -9.6     6
# 5     dna   30.0     5
# 4     dna   20.0     4
# 3     rna    3.0     3
# 2     rna    2.0     2
```